# Constructing Listview with edittext

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and its rows contains edittext. And length of listview is 7. when entering the value in first row it also insert in 7th row. I stucked in this problem for last 2 days. Please anyone help me.`package

```
com.teacherapp.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;
import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;
import com.teacherapp.async.GetMarksAsync;
import com.teacherapp.bean.TeacherBean;
import com.teacherapp.fragments.MarkeUpdateFragment;
import com.teacherapp.utility.ConstantTeacher;
import com.wemited.schoolfly.teacherapp.R;

public class MarksListAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    List<TeacherBean> recentitems;
    LayoutInflater inflate;
    TeacherBean item;
    AlertDialog alertDialog, fpDialog;
    public static final String KEY_SETTING = "setting";
    public static CheckBox check_img;
    Context context;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean isChecking = true;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int mCheckedId = R.id.type1;
    public static String status_all;
    int position1;
    //String marks;
    public MarksListAdaptor(Activity context, List<TeacherBean> recentitems,
            String string) {
        this.recentitems = recentitems;

        inflate = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        status_all = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recentitems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return recentitems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txt_name, txt_father;
        public CircularImageView logo_img;
        public EditText edt_marks, edt_grad;

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        item = recentitems.get(position);


        final TeacherBean item1 = (TeacherBean) getItem(position);
        View myview = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            myview = inflate.inflate(R.layout.stud_mark_list_item, null);
        }
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_name = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        holder.txt_father = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_father);
        holder.logo_img = (CircularImageView) myview.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.edt_marks = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.edt_marks);
        holder.edt_grad = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.edt_grad);
        holder.txt_name.setText("" + item.getStudent_name());
        holder.txt_father.setText("" + item.getStudent_roll_no());
        if (status_all.equals("0")) {
            holder.edt_marks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.edt_grad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.edt_grad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.edt_marks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        String logo = ConstantTeacher.img_base + item.getStudent_img();
        holder.logo_img.setAnimation(null);
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.logo_img, logo,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, new UrlImageViewCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView,
                            Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url,
                            boolean loadedFromCache) {

                        if (!loadedFromCache) {

                        }
                    }
                });

        holder.edt_marks.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                String marks = holder.edt_marks.getText().toString();
                        GetMarksAsync.status_list.set(position, marks); 

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        holder.edt_grad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                String grad = holder.edt_grad.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("marks"+grad);
                GetMarksAsync.status_list.set(position, grad);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        return myview;
    }
}
```

This is my XML layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wemited.teacherapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_box_corners_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".23"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".52"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/app_theme_color"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_father"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/app_green"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_marks"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_box_corners_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/app_theme_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/GrayLight"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_grad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edt_marks"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_box_corners_blue"
                android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/app_theme_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/GrayLight"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```